# CSS - background-color not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, sass, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code:

```
.skills_column {
  padding: 50px !important;
  padding-top: 60px !important;

  &.--light {
    background-color: white;
  }
  &.--dark {
    background-color: #ced4db;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```

There are 3 columns, a light one, and two dark ones.
All of this works in Chrome & Firefox, however, it does not work in IE11:

While the light one is white as expected, the two other columns which are supposed to be dark, are also white when viewed in IE11.

What could the problem be?
I also tried to add `filter: none !important;` because I read that somewhere, but that does not seem to make a difference although I might have not applied it correctly, I am not sure.

I am also using flexbox, if that should make a difference. But my problem here is with the background colors not being applied.

Comment: its mostly the flexbox thats affecting this. Do you have `flex` or `min-height` property on the flex items?

Comment: I only have one additional class which is applied to a child of each column, which centers an svg. But this is not directly applied to the column itself: `.content_centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}`  - apart from this my HTML for each column looks like this: `<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 skills_column --dark"> ... </div>`

Comment: hmm doesn't look harmful. Can you remove the double hyphen from the class names `--dark` & try. I have a feeling IE doesnt like this.

Comment: I'll try this. This might be it. Will report back shortly

Comment: Sorry, that took me some time. That was precisely it. I changed everything to underscores, so e.g. `_light` , and that works now. Thanks a lot. If you would want to submit this as an answer, I would pick that of course.

Comment: Sure, glad it helped. Everyday i see issues like this I feel sad for IE devs and users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try removing the double hyphen from your class names(`--dark`, `--light`). I have a feeling IE doesn't like BEM representations. Maybe single underscore or double underscore works.

```
.skills_column {
  padding: 50px !important;
  padding-top: 60px !important;

  &._light {
    background-color: white;
  }
  &._dark {
    background-color: #ced4db;
  }

  @include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```